# Import strings from .txt and searching for first numeric character - python

Tags: python, import, export, text-files

I am a total noob with python (programming in fact) but I hope you can help :)

I have a .txt file with a list of strings containing addresses.

I want to import it to Python and then search for the first numberic character and then create a new column for it...like

input

```
'Elm Street 12' 
'Baker Street 143'
```

and output

```
'Elm Street 12' , 12
'Baker Street 143' , 14
```

and save it to .txt.

I am trying to do if from the windows cmd.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('file.txt') as inn:
    for line in inn:
        print "%s %s" % (line, [int(item) for item in line.split(' ') if item.isdigit()])
```

Comment: Hi Jakob,i get invalid syntax - %s"

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a `dict`. Loop through and use `re` to find your numeric characters, use that as a key in the dict to each string. If you expect to have duplicates.

```
import re
results = {}
for s in ['Elm Street 12', 'Baker Street 143']:
    match = re.search(r'\d+', s)
    if match:
        results[match.group()] = s

>>> results
<<< {'12': 'Elm Street 12', '143': 'Baker Street 143'}
```

Comment: Why use RE where you don't really need it?

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for

```
import re

input = '''Elm Street 12
Baker Street 143'''
output = ""

rows = input.split("\n")
for row in rows:
    m = re.search(r'\d+', row)
    output += "{0} {1}\n".format(row, m.group())

print output
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
regx = re.compile("^('.+ (\d+)')",re.MULTILINE)

with open('Copie de fileinput.txt','r+') as f:
    mod = regx.sub('\\1 , \\2',f.read())
    f.seek(0,0)
    f.write(mod)
```

Note that I understood that there are quotes ' in the file. I doubt of that, but your output have quotes in it, so my regex has quotes.... You will remove thgem if there are no quotes in fact

Intead of recording data in a flat file, you should better use the pickle module